# Is possible to execute a key binding in a function?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, major-mode, keyboard-macros

Say, the `C-M-j` is bound to `c-indent-new-comment-line` for c-mode (and c++-mode) and `indent-new-comment-line` for other modes, but I want to define a function that will execute `C-M-j` to `c-indent-new-comment-line` in c-mode (and c++-mode) and `indent-new-comment-line` in other modes.

Is there any simple way that I can just embed the shortcut but not check the current major mode and then execute the different functions in `defun...`?

Example:

```
(defun example-fn ()
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line)
  (execute-C-M-j)
  (next-line))
```

The `(execute-C-M-j)` is what I want, execute the key not the command it is bound to, but I don't know how to implement this?

Comment: Something like this?:  `(defun example-fn () (interactive) (if (eq major-mode 'c-mode) (message "Hello-world!") (message "Happy birthday!"))) (define-key global-map [f5] 'example-fn)`

Comment: What does a function which uses `C-M-j` to do `X` mean? After executing the function, you would want the desired shortcuts to be bound?

Comment: @lawlist No, you are saying the normal way(defun and then set-key), I mean the key is part of the function defined, you will execute a lot of commands including the key if you execute the function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`funcall`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html) and `key-binding` to do this:

```
(funcall (key-binding (kbd "C-M-j")))
```

will execute the function currently bound to `C-M-j`.

`funcall` lets you pass in arguments as well, if needed.

Alternatively, you can use [`call-interactively`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Call.html) to call a command bound to a key like this:

```
(call-interactively (key-binding (kbd "C-M-j")))
```

Comment: Thank you, the [call-interactively](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Call.html) is exactly what I want.